# MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() returns multiples of 2048 instead of current position

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

My application uses the `MediaPlayer` class to play some sound samples, and I have a Seekbar to track the progress of playback. On all of my test phones but 1, everything works fine. However, on the **Sony Xperia**, I encounter a weird bug with the progress tracking. Audio playback works just fine, but when I try to `MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()`, I only get increments of 2048.

For instance, on the LG G2 (running Android 4.4.2), I see values like these:

```
0, 213, 279, 348, 416, ...
```

which allows me to update the SeekBar accordingly. However, on the Sony Xperia (also running Android 4.4.2), I always get these values:

```
0, 0, 0, ... , 2048, 2048, 2048, ... , 4096, 4096, ... , 6144, 6144, ...
```

Audio playback works fine, but my progress bar jumps in increments of 2 seconds. I'd rather not have to implement another timing system since the existing schema works for all but the Xperia. Since the G2 runs this fine on 4.4.2, I think I can rule out the Android version as the issue.

Has anyone seen this issue in the Sony Xperia or other devices? Is this issue easily remedied?